# tab style with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

**I have created tab style interface using css and javascript with only two tabs which is working fine.But i want to add more tabs to it and i am not getting how can i write javascript code for it to show current active tab and its contents and hide all other tabs and their contents**

---

Following is my html code :

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="tabbox">
        <a href="#" id="signup" class="tab signup">Signup</a>
        <a href="#" id="login" class="tab select">Login</a&gt;
    </div>

    <div id="panel">
        <div id="loginbox">Login Form</div>
        <div id="signupbox"&gt;Signup Form</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

This is my javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $(".tab").click(function()
    {
        var X=$(this).attr('id');

        if(X=='signup')
        {
            $("#login").removeClass('select');
            $("#signup").addClass('select');
            $("#loginbox").slideUp();
            $("#signupbox").slideDown();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#signup").removeClass('select');
            $("#login").addClass('select');
            $("#signupbox").slideUp();
            $("#loginbox").slideDown();
        }

    });

});
```

This is working fine for two tabs but if i add more tabs to it say :

```
<div id="container">

      <div id="tabbox">
          <a href="#" id="signup" class="tab signup">Signup</a>
          <a href="#" id="login" class="tab select">Login</a&gt;
          <a href="#" id="basic" class="tab basicinfo">Basicinfo</a>
          <a href="#" id="contact" class="tab contact info">contactinfo</a>
      </div>

      <div id="panel">
          <div id="loginbox">Login Form</div>
          <div id="signupbox"&gt;Signup Form</div>
          <div id="basicbox">Basic information</div>
          <div id="contactbox">Contact information</div>
      </div>

</div>
```

**Then if i use previous javascript function i will have to add lot more lines to it and i am not getting how can i do it in short and simple way.
What changes do i have to make in my javascript function..**

Comment: an id is supposed to be unique, your html has 3 elements with the same id... before anything else, that needs to be fixed. Als, if `x` is the id of `$(this)`, why use the `$('signup')` selector? it scans the dom tree all over again... use `$(this)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `id`s (that have to be unique - you are using them multiple times) and `classes` in a weird way (you did before your edit...).

For a basic setup like:

```
<div id="container">

      <div id="tabbox">
          <a href="#A" class="tab">A</a> <!-- note the URL fragments pointing to actual ids -->
          <a href="#B" class="tab">B</a>
          <a href="#C" class="tab">C</a>
          <a href="#D" class="tab">D</a>
      </div>

      <div id="panel">
          <div id="A" class="tab">A Content</div> <!-- ID attributes are only used once -->
          <div id="B" class="tab">B Content</div>
          <div id="C" class="tab">C Content</div>
          <div id="D" class="tab">D Content</div>
      </div>

</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You could just use some lines of jQuery to get things working:

```
$('div.tab').hide().first().slideDown(); //show first

$('a.tab').click(function(){
    var targetID = $(this).attr('href'); //store element that triggered the click event
    $('div.tab:visible').slideUp(function(){ //hide visible tab
        $(targetID).slideDown(); //slide down newly selected tab
    });
});​
```

See **[a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkATJ/2/)**

Also read about **[ids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id)** and **[classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Class_selectors)** at MDN

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$(".tab").click(function()
    {
        var x = this.id, // equivalent to $(this).attr('id'), but slightly faster/more-simple
            show = $('#' + x + 'box');
        if (show.length){
            $('.contentBox').slideUp(500);
            show.slideDown(500);
        }

    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Kn5vm/).

Or the following (equivalent to the above, but using a callback):

```
$(".tab").click(function()
    {
        var x = this.id,
            show = $('#' + x + 'box');
        if (show.length){
            $('.contentBox')
                .slideUp(500,
                         function(){
                             show.slideDown(500);
                         });
        }

    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Kn5vm/1/).

This assumes the following:

1. That all of the 'boxes' you want to show have the class of `contentBox`,
2. That the id of the 'box' you want to show takes the form of the `id` of the link that's clicked followed by the word 'box', so clicking the `#signup` link reveals `#signupbox`.

---

**Edited** to include a CSS-only option:

With the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="tabbox">
        <a href="#signupbox" id="signup" class="tab signup">Signup</a> <!-- note the href -->
        <a href="#loginbox" id="login" class="tab select">Login</a>
    </div>

    <div id="panel">
        <div id="loginbox" class="contentBox">Login Form</div>
        <div id="signupbox" class="contentBox">Signup Form</div>
    </div>

</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
.contentBox {
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear;
    transition: height 1s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contentBox:target {
    height: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear;
    transition: height 1s linear;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Kn5vm/3/).

Comment: thanks for this solution..I tried this and working fine but i am accepting the solution given by m90 because his solution giving slideup and slidedown effects smoothness and in your solution it feels like page is getting stuck for some seconds or so.i tried to slideup and slieddown with different arguments like fast,100 but still i was not getting smooth slideup slidedown effects.but thanks for the solution

Comment: No worries; after all you're meant to accept the most-useful answer that you actually use to solve your problem. =)

Answer (score 0):

if you give a class to the content divs before you open one tab you can close all the others e.g.

```
$(".tab-content").slideUp();
$("#loginbox").slideDown();
```

You also need to know which tab you have clicked on e.g.

```
$(".tab").click(function(){
   var id = this.id;
   var current_tab_content = '#'+id+'box';

   $(".tab-content").slideUp();
   $(current_tab_content).slideDown();

  });
```

I have not tested this but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I don't believe that `$(this).id;` will work. You need to either use jQuery methods on the jQuery `this` object: `$(this).attr('id');`, or convert from a jQuery object to a DOM object: `$(this)[0].id;` or just use native DOM in the first place: `this.id;`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but maybe works:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {

    $("#tabbox a:not(.selected)").click(function() {
        $($("#tabbox a.selected").attr('href')).slideUp();
        $("#tabbox a.selected").removeClass('select');
        $(this).addClass('select');
        $($(this).attr('href')).slideDown();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="tabbox">
        <a href="#signupbox" id="signup" class="tab signup">Signup</a>
        <a href="#loginbox" id="login" class="tab select">Login</a>
    </div>

    <div id="panel">
        <div id="loginbox">Login Form</div>
        <div id="signupbox">Signup Form</div>
    </div>

</div>
```